# How to separate characters of a word in c# windows form app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 questions:

1. I want to get all file's name in a folder.How can I do this?
2. how can I separate first 8 characters of a word?

I wanna make a c# windows form app that is able to get a folder address and separate the pictures that their name is equal(first 8 characters show the date they had taken)

Answer (score 1):

1 You can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to get list of files.

2 You can use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to get name of file.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.*").Select(x => x.Substring(8)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Can you make an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following files names:

C:\folder\12345678Picture1.jpg
C:\folder\12345678Picture2.jpg
C:\folder\12345678Picture3.jpg

Try something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

//...

public class PictureInfo
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//...

var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\folder");
var pictureInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Select(x => new PictureInfo
{
    Date = x.Name.Substring(0, 8),
    Name = x.Name.Substring(8)
}).ToArray();
```

`pictureInfos` will now contain the following objects:

Date: 12345678, Name: Picture1.jpg
Date: 12345678, Name: Picture2.jpg
Date: 12345678, Name: Picture3.jpg